# Why is $(-1)^n \int_{-1}^1 (x^2-1)^n \frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}} (x^2-1)^n dx = (-1)^n(2n!)\int_{-1}^1 (x^2-1)^n dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I was reading some notes and came across this equality, which I do not quite understand: $$(-1)^n \int_{-1}^1 (x^2-1)^n \frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}} (x^2-1)^n dx = (-1)^n(2n)!\int_{-1}^1 (x^2-1)^n dx$$

I was thinking that $\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}} (x^2-1)^n= (2n)!$ but I do not quite grasp it... It probably can be solved via the product rule, but I would be very pleased if someone could help me with this.

Comment: The leading term in $(1-x^2)^n$ is $x^{2n}$ & when you differentiate $2n$ times all the other terms will give zero & this term will give $(2n)!$ ... so you are absolutely correct.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Exactly the same what I have written in my answer!

Comment: Okay... I see it.. I was stuck in my thoughts thinking that differentiating $2n$ times would leave me with $1$ ... my bad.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :**

Expand $(x^2-1)^{n}$ using binomial theorem.

> Since $n \in \mathbb N $, The highest power of $x$ in this expansion will be $2n$ which when taken derivative $2n$ times, will turn into $(2n)!$. Rest all the powers of $x$, being less than $2n$ will vanish

Comment: How do you make the text magically appear when one does a mouse over on the box ?... that is really cool !

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Because I am wizard of LaTeX...lol, you can use it by starting any sentence with `>!`.It is used to hide spoiler.You can click the edit button and see how it works.